# How are parameterized queries done on free text CONTAINS with logical operators?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am dynamically creating queries in SQL Server that are parameterized.  When it comes to the CONTAINS predicate I have run into a question that I couldn’t find an answer to.

If the CONATINS will have logical operators (OR, AND, AND NOT)  do I have to enumerate each of the values or do I use one parameter for all?

Here is a static example:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE CONTAINS(ColumName, ‘Cat and Dog’);
```

Is this the correct parameterized example?

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE CONTAINS(ColumName, ‘@Q1 and @Q2’);

@Q1 = “Cat”
@Q2 = “Dog”
```

Or is this the correct approach?

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE CONTAINS(ColumName, ‘@Q1’);

@Q1 = “Cat and Dog”
```

Or is it something entirely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I asked the question I didn't have a database with full text enabled that I could test against.  I was just writing the code and unit tests.  Since then I managed to find a DB that I could test with.

The second example was the closest.  The only problem was the the parameter was quoted so it would have searched on the literal "@Q1".

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE CONTAINS(ColumName, @Q1);

@Q1 = “Cat and Dog”
```

If the query needs the a generation term, proximity term or wieghted term then those need to be in the parameter too.

```
@Q1 = 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, Cat) and FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, Dog)'
@Q1 = 'FORMSOF(THESAURUS, Cat) and FORMSOF(THESAURUS, "Dog")'
@Q1 = 'Cat NEAR Dog'
```